# Apache Camel - Reading files with loopDoWhile and pollEnrich - Once at a time required

Tags: java, apache-camel

A part of my Camel route is reading files from a server and analysing their content to enrich a main route.
Therefore I cannot use .from(filesFolder). I thought using pollEnrich would be a solution, but since it picks only one file, I had to loop around (here using loopDoWhile).

```
String filesSource = "file:////server/folder/?move=proc&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true";

this.from("direct:start") //
  .loopDoWhile(new BatchNotFinishedPredicate()) //
    .pollEnrich(filesSource, new PollEnrichStrategy()) //
      .choice() //
        .when(doProcessPredicate) //
          .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "- processing ${file:path}.") //
        .endChoice() //
      .otherwise() //
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "- NOT processing ${file:path}.") //
      .endChoice() //
    .end() //
  .end() //
; //
```

The problem is, that the files are **all** being locked, maintained in memory and not released until the whole folder is done.
This is therefore working well with a couple of files, but with thousands of files (like needed), it is slow and giving an "out of memory" after an hour or so.
Some hours would be OK, but it needs to **lock+handle+unlock** few files at a time.
I was looking for some parameter I could set within pollEnrich (or loopDoWhile?) to produce the expected behavior without having luck.
Within "file", I tested the parameter "maxMessagesPerPoll=2". This handles 2 files and **stop** polling.
Any ideas?

"localWorkDirectory" as mentioned in the comments, seems to provide a better performance, but it doesn't solve the main problem of locking/unlocking all the files.

The camel-version is **2.18.0** + cannot be upgraded :(

Comment: Can you check if the localWorkDirectory parameter works for you? https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_query_parameters_92_parameters

Comment: Check out the claimcheck EIP.

Comment: Claim Check comes with a newer Camel version. Is not part of 2.18

Comment: even if the use of a localWorkDirectory does not solve the problem of locking all the files, the performance is better. So, still searching...